# Jenkins CVS Plugin incorrectly uses slave key path for CVS rlog

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am attempting to configure my first distributed build on Jenkins.  I know the two computers I am using work properly standalone, as they both have Jenkins running on them with the project integrating successfully on each.

In my new configuration, a Mac is the master and a Ubuntu Linux box (10.04 LTS) is the slave.  I'm using the CVS plugin to check out my source.  I have public / private key pairs for CVS authentication on both machines that work successfully stand alone.  The id_rsa and known_hosts key paths are defined by environment variables which are configured per node (including the master) in the Manage Nodes configuration pages on the master, as well as the Configure System page for the master.

When I execute the distributed build, it successfully checks out on the master and slave.  It successfully runs cvs rlog on the master.  Then it attempts to run cvs rlog in the slave job execution.  But, it uses the slave private key path.  The job fails.  My understanding is cvs rlog is always run on the master.  So, the path choice seems wrong to me.

How to I force the rlog path back to the master path?  Is this a bug or should my configuration be different than it is?

Comment: Anyone running the CVS plugin on a distributed build?  It would probably help a ton just to hear how you are successfully doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13764) in the plugin which has now been fixed in V2.10.

I have multiple distributed setups running, but using Pserver for authentication, hence them all working.

Comment: Agree.  Discovered this too after much digging.  Was not aware that it was fixed in 2.10.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: In case anyone is stuck on 2.9 or earlier, I temporarily worked around this by making the master path resolve on all slave machines.  It was a little tricky when mixing Windows, Linux, and Mac environments, but Windows nicely treated // as C:, so life was good.